# Diagonal of (self) product of doubly stochastic transition matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

By doubly stochastic and transition, I mean each row sum and column sum of a matrix is 1 and each element of the matrix is in [0, 1]. Here, I am considering the matrix is n by n where n is finite. 
I'm curious to know that if P and Q are doubly stochastic transition matrices, can we say something about the diagonal elements of PQ? (something like they are positive.) 
What about the diagonal elements of $P^2$ where P is a doubly stochastic transition matrix? 
(Eventually, I want them to be greater than zero to show that for discrete-time Markov chain with doubly stochastic transition matrix and finite state space, all states are recurrent.) 
Edit: As suggested by @kimchilover, there is an example that doesn't do what I want a doubly stochastic transition matrix to do. However, the particular example gives an irreducible finite MC, so it eventually does what I want to show which is that all states are recurrent. Is this always the case? If it is, how do I go about showing this? 
Thanks!

Comment: If $P=Q=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0}$ (which is doubly stochastic) then the diagonal elements of $PQ=P^2$ are not positive.

Comment: Though @kimchilover's example in a discrete time Markov chain with three states, all of the states are still recurrent with this particular transition matrix, so maybe there is something else the OP can look for besides all diagonal elements being positive

Comment: @kimchilover Thank you for the comment. I have actually come up with exactly the same example right after uploading the question. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\ P\ $ is an $\ n\times n\ $ doubly stochastic matrix then
$$
\mathbb{1}^\top P= \mathbb{1}^\top\ .
$$
Therefore, $\ \frac{1}{n} \mathbb{1}^\top\ $ is a stationary distribution of the corresponding Markov chain.  But if $\ i\ $ is a transient state of a Markov chain then every stationary distribution $\ \pi\ $ of that chain must have $\ \pi_i=0\ $.  It follows that no Markov chain with a doubly stochastic transition matrix can have any transient states.

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question.